# Event resizing, event color and text color not working in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using jquery's fullcalendar plugin, but the resizing ability is not working, also, the event background color is always white and i can't change the text color in the events.
Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#fullcalendar").fullCalendar({
        "allDayDefault": false,
        "allDaySlot": true,
        "allDayText": "dia inteiro",
        "axisFormat": "HH:mm",
        "buttonText": {
            "today": "Ir para hoje",
            "month": "Mensal",
            "week": "Semanal",
            "day": "Diário"
        },
        "columnFormat": {
            "month": "ddd",
            "week": "ddd ' - ' dd' / 'MM",
            "day": "dddd"
        },
        "dayNames": [
            "Domingo",
            "Segunda-Feira",
            "Terça-Feira",
            "Quarta-Feira",
            "Quinta-Feira",
            "Sexta-Feira",
            "Sábado"
        ],
        "dayNamesShort": ["Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "Sáb"],
        "defaultView": "agendaWeek",
        "disableResizing": false,
        "editable": true,
        "events": "/cmvida/ajax/evento",
        "eventDurationEditable": true,
        "header": {
            "left": "prev,next today",
            "center": "title",
            "right": "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
        },
        "monthNames": [
            "Janeiro",
            "Fevereiro",
            "Março",
            "Abril",
            "Maio",
            "Junho",
            "Julho",
            "Agosto",
            "Setembro",
            "Outubro",
            "Novembro",
            "Dezembro"
        ],
        "monthNamesShort": [
            "Jan",
            "Fev",
            "Mar",
            "Abr",
            "Mai",
            "Jun",
            "Jul",
            "Ago",
            "Set",
            "Out",
            "Nov",
            "Dez"
        ],
        "select": function(start, end, allDay) {
            var dataEvento = "";
            var dataInicial = get_ptBR_date_string(start).split(" ");
            var horaInicial = dataInicial[1].split(":");
            var dataFinal = get_ptBR_date_string(end).split(" ");
            var horaFinal = dataFinal[1].split(":");

            dataEvento += diaDaSemana[start.getDay()] + ", ";
            dataEvento += pad(start.getDate(), 2) + "/" + pad(start.getMonth() + 1,2) + "/" + start.getFullYear() + " ";
            dataEvento += start.toLocaleString().split(" ")[1].split(":")[0] + ":" + start.toLocaleString().split(" ")[1].split(":")[1];
            dataEvento += " - ";
            dataEvento += end.toLocaleString().split(" ")[1].split(":")[0] + ":" + end.toLocaleString().split(" ")[1].split(":")[1];

            $("#data_inicial_novo_evento").val(dataInicial[0]);
            $("#hora_inicial_novo_evento").val(horaInicial[0] + ":" + horaInicial[1]);
            $("#data_final_novo_evento").val(dataFinal[0]);
            $("#hora_final_novo_evento").val(horaFinal[0] + ":" + horaFinal[1]);
            $("#span_data_evento").html(dataEvento);
            $("#form_novo_evento").dialog("open");
        },
        "selectHelper": true,
        "selectable": true,
        "theme": false,
        "timeFormat": "HH:mm{ - HH:mm}",
        "titleFormat": {
            "month": "MMMM 'de' yyyy",
            "week": "dd MMM[ yyyy]{ '-' dd MMM yyyy}",
            "day": "dd 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy"
        }
    });
</script>
```

I already searched a lot here, but can't find the solution. All the dependencies that fullcalendar need are being included. Jquery UI have all the necessary components for resizing. I can't realize what is wrong. There is no error on the browser console.

Comment: show html and css as well

Comment: @ariel i've posted an example in my site. You can see it at http://www.andremarcondes.com.br/fullcalendar.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue. And it was very DUMB :@
The fullcalendar.print.css was being imported on the code. :(